# How to import a file in the ROOT folder from a file in a subfolder?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror, directory-structure

I'm working with Python 3.8 and I have a project tree as:

```
project folder/
|__OuterFile.py
|__folder1/
    |__ folder2/
        |__ folder3/
            |__ InnerFile.py
```

How could I import OuterFile.py, in the project folder (root folder), from inside InnerFile.py?

I tried to:

- add `__init__.py` in `/project_folder/` and in each subfolder;
- and add the import line `from .... import OuterFile` in `InputFile.py`
  but it gives me the error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Answer (score 0):

You could append to the path the parent directory like this: (add as many "../" as for how many levels you should go up in the folder hierarchy)

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
```

And then you could import the file like if it is in the same directory:

```
import OuterFile
```